# issue with enable_if a template member function of template class, on a non-type template parameter, when defining it out of line

Tags: c++, templates, function-definition, member-functions

This issue occurs when trying to split the template into declaration and definition for ease of reading.

Consider this MWE

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2, int N = 6>
struct Foo {
  template <int N2 = N, typename std::enable_if<N2 == 6, bool>::type = true>
  Foo(int i);

  template <int N2 = N, typename std::enable_if<N2 != 6, bool>::type = true>
  Foo(double d);

};

template <typename T1, typename T2, int N>
template <int N2, typename std::enable_if<N == 6, bool>::type >
Foo<T1, T2, N>::Foo(int i){}

template <typename T1, typename T2, int N>
template <int N2, typename std::enable_if<N != 6, bool>::type >
Foo<T1, T2, N>::Foo(double d){}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Foo<int, double, 3> foo1(4.5);
    Foo<int, double, 6> foo2(4);
    return 0; 
}
```

I want to have the class template have one constructor when `N == 6` and another one if not.
The above code works when putting the constructor body with the declaration, but I can't seem to find the right syntax when splitting them.

The compiler error from [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCBAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8YF2mA7pQgRMxASZPn5cFZj2BQy19QRFkTFxCbZ1DU3ZrcM9fSVlCQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CYbbgQAnomYAPoExEyECofYJhoAgk/PBJgsiQYfB0en52YbD2ABUuKQ9gDGKxMKCzBCwgQ9hE/gARPb%2BB5vBTXLwOPYAMVQqAOAHYrC89pDPt8mL9Dm5EcizGjkRCoUDYTj0CAQNDovQLngqAyIizDqiJRiIdFibQHryoazcZgsZTCcSIEy8HMyVZSZKXm8qR8vj9YQymWLWRF2WdocDubz%2BYLhaKWWAwFLAntZZ4FSAlVKVWrnlSiagIOglgLYeg5iZyYnDa8jQbDhTU%2B8aea/sd7ZzQeDIQWYXCEYJkaHTbT6UcrfCS4Cy06%2BcxY0KRUcURLvTK5QGgxtHi8IwywRCQY2IgGI1rKzrE/qU28a7mGRyyxOmw7YVOK0iZ8PVzm6Rb65WxXbm46CDy20wO27u3tPX3fQPh4r7X8R88x0c277lWX4gHO0ZeLGezxkuyZvPBLxMiwtwMPOSL1MAyAQsgCD1AAVHhewYQAbrqsHquGxKWoIEIQbGEIbA8ez8KgXAQJIAB0ACsCYbJmVKUag1EELRMb0BCmLDsxxJmOxvH8QJxCYAQywMHsGgZgcaaohwCy0JwXG8H4HBaKQqCcG41jWHsChLCsFpmBsPCkAQmi6QsADWICSP4HEAJxcVxfkbP4pL%2BJIZhcFwZjSPpHCSEZblmZwvAKCAGguW5CxwLASBoF8dBxOQlD5YkhXxDshjAFIGhMAoSgNKQWDEXgqwAGp4JgADuADygKcM5NC0B8xBpRA0RJdEYT1CcA28FNzDECcPXRNoVSudwvD5Wwgg9QwtCzSZvBYNEXjAG4Yi0Glm1NZ8VXiEdTV4Ep1TEZg12mZgqhVF4HxJYi7RJbQeDRDcS0eFgSXXHgLBzQsVAGMACgdd1fWMHNMiCCIYjsFImPyEoahJbo4IGEYKBWZY%2Bgg2lsCcnyeDAIwpBvfEHAbBsfnuWZiSdNdvCoKzxB4FgtMQAslTVM4ECuGMLRBAw6DTAM8TgnkaQCHLejq50yulIM4KS503SjJ4zR6EbNQjL0YT9PrquTKbWTyziUy2zMBsS3ZqwSHpBmJY95kcHsqgABz%2BAAtOFeyVUYexSBxGiJ3sEB1Q1fO6hAuCECQByOVwcy8BtWhzJ5Eh%2BRxpJcBopJmH5fkaDFgWSBs%2BicAlpDGaZQepelmVHdlMCICASwEIkv3FRApXlREMKcPULDEaHEdMDHZPAPHnFJ59%2BBEMLPLgvwWOiOIeNHwTKjqI9JOkF1NyJHDbccIZndJUHPW/ePSKoFQIfh1Hkg15VU3onZOqd6pxAzinDwBV6DEDzk5Qu/cS5lw5hxDmGDMFYKfh3LuAsUq2D7sXbmcUzAB27gQ4hpcWZxFSM4SQQA%3D%3D) is

```
<source>:15:17: error: out-of-line definition of 'Foo<T1, T2, N>' does not match any declaration in 'Foo<T1, T2, N>'
Foo<T1, T2, N>::Foo(int i){}
                ^~~
<source>:19:17: error: out-of-line definition of 'Foo<T1, T2, N>' does not match any declaration in 'Foo<T1, T2, N>'
Foo<T1, T2, N>::Foo(double d){}
                ^~~
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

What is my mistake here?

---

I can use C++20 if needed, but solutions for 17 or 14 would be preferable.

Comment: Hi, the question title and tags may be misleading (it seems more an issue with out of line definition) otherwise, it seems legit for me.

Comment: can you suggest better tags for this problem?

Comment: I proposed an edit. We'll see if it is accepted. NB MarekR comment will solve your issue, yet I would still be interested in understanding why your implementation does not work.

Comment: Which comment are you referring to? I am not seeing any others. Is the enable-if unrelated to the issue here? otherwise I would keep the tag.

Comment: So would I need template specializations to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Works [here](https://godbolt.org/z/q4qTcd4W5) once typos fixed (`N == 6` -> `N2 == 6`).

Comment: Typos: duplicated definitions (in class and outside of class) and in declaration place `N2` is used in definition `N` is used - making this inconsistent. https://godbolt.org/z/GW7Pa1Wfv so voting close as typo.

Comment: C++20 version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/czT1Y8Ez9) (with `requires`).

Comment: Damn, I shouldn't have tried this late at night. With the typos fixed, my actual use case compiles, but during linking of another cpp instantiating the template, the constructor definition is missing.

Comment: FYI this version is more concise in a couple of ways: `template <int N2 = N> Foo(std::enable_if_t<N2 == 6, int> i);`

Comment: If you have linking issue then this is another topic, possibly [you didn't place definitions in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) (splinting template code into declarations and definitions is a good clue this is a problem).

Comment: @oarfish MarekR proposed to implement your constructor with ```if constexpr``` inside a single constructor, which would be much simpler.

Comment: @MarekR Indeed I am not doing that, on purpose. But both files (declaration and definition) are included in the cpp, they are just split for readability.